# RaiseCanExecuteChanged COM Exception during Navigation?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

**Update**

Uploaded sample project: https://github.com/subt13/BugSamples

I have reproduced an error that has been occurring in a Windows 10 UAP application that utilizes the MVVMLight framework.

I receive the error below during navigation while the CPU is under heavy load (~20-25%) and the page is "heavy" (large images, lots of controls, etc., etc.)

> at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ICommandAdapterHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__3(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()    at
>   RaiseExecuteChangeRepo.ViewModel.MainViewModel.d__17.MoveNext()

In the sample, the error occurs on `RaiseCanExecuteChanged();`

```
    private async void ExecuteLoadDataCommandAsync()
    {
        // cause the app to slow done.
        var data = await Task.Run(() => GetData()); 

        if (data != null)
        {
            this.Data.Clear();

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                this.Data.Add(new AnotherVM(item));
            }
        }

        // have the select job command rerun its condition
        this.SelectCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    // slow down the page
    public List<DataItem> GetData()
    {
        var myList = new List<DataItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
            myList.Add(new DataItem("Welcome to MVVM Light"));

        }

        return myList;
    }
```

Nothing special is happening during navigation other than the command associated with `ExecuteLoadDataCommandAsync()` is getting called to load data.

```
<Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadDataCommand}">
   </Core:InvokeCommandAction>
</Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
```

To reproduce, simply toggle from one page to the other rapidly for a few seconds and then just wait.  After not too long the exception will be raised.

Comment: E_FAIL is only a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting in WinRT.  It is completely useless to diagnose the underlying problem.  It *might* be a threading problem, always non-zero odds for it in async/await code.  But then again it could be anything.  You'll have to find a reliable repro scenario, don't plan to do accomplish anything for the next week.

Comment: @HansPassant - Yup, working on that.

Comment: My guess is that it is caused by "toggle from one page to the other rapidly for a few seconds and then just wait." - your `async` operations are still running, and when they complete they try to interact with a XAML tree that is no longer active. To fix, make sure you're still the active page before raising the events.

Comment: By setting the DataContext to null when leaving the main page (overriding OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs)). I've been able to fix the COM Exception from the RaiseCanExecuteChanged() method BUT, I'm now getting another E_FAIL exception from somewhere else. I do not know how it apply to your real application but you might have to cancel the load when leaving the page or maybe use a cache to avoid reloading everytime the data.

Comment: I too suspect it's a re-entrancy issue. You should guard `ExecuteLoadDataCommandAsync` from re-entrancy and add some cancellation logic (so `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` wouldn't be fired redundantly). There're many ways of doing that, some are discussed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2014/03/03/async-re-entrancy-and-the-patterns-to-deal-with-it.aspx).

Comment: @O.O Did you ever find the cause? I have a similar problem I don't understand.

Comment: @Amenti - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing my issue by adding the following event to the code behind.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = null;
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```